# How to transfer all user settings and preferences to root and delete all users except root?

Tags: 18.04, root, user-management

How to transfer all  files, settings and  preferences from a user to root and delete all users but root ?
I find it tedious and time-consuming to work on ubuntu 18.04 "LTS" gui when I'm not root.
Root login is enabled and just want to transfer every thing from the user to the root and make the system a root only pc.
the question is how to do it and not why shouldn't it be done.

Comment: Gnome is not designed to run as root. You are asking for support to do an unsupported and untested action, so you probably won't get many quality answers. If you run into problems, you will be on your own.

Comment: Its already running smoothly as root which means it is designed to run as root. The question is how to transfer every thing to the root account and then delete the other guys to save space and file tree complexity. If I run into problems, I will try to fix them, ask, reinstall, install different distro or even switch to windows to get my work done fast. Thank you

Comment: @user535733 it seems that the new gnome is not designed to run as normal user as well. Too many bugs and unclean gui elements such as panels and desktop icons overlapping and delays.

Comment: @user535733 Do you mean it is desigen not to run well as root? Its better to show warning messages and let the user decide. Unless they are planning selling it to apple.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux, it's not recommends to do that. You do that only if you have enough reason.

However, if you insist, copy all files and dirs (including hidden files started with ".") from `/home/USERNAME/` to `/root/` and `chown root:root -R` them. That won't insure it can seamlessly work. After that you still have to encounter problems, cause in some files user name and home folder path is written there.

Desktop itself runs well on root. If you already logged in desktop as root, don't copy the files started with `.xauth` from user home folder.

Comment: Thank you Bob. I will try the nautilus search bar or SearchMonkey  to search for the user name occurrences with and without regular expressions.

Comment: I have more than enough reasons and will test your suggestions in a virtual machine. I'm even trying to automate this using a bash script. +1 for that.

Comment: I copied almost everything one by one manualy, fixed the sound problems by copying files from the autostart folder and changed the environmental variables path. some applications like android studio were smart enough to find the copied sdk. I will keep the normal user for a while in case more files need to be copied to the root home.